# What does the right arrow mean in a search and replace operation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the following image, you can see an arrow pointing to the right at each replacement:

[image]

When hovering it, no tooltip is shown; clicking it doesn't do anything either.

**Question:**

What's the meaning and/or purpose of that arrow that points to the right?